# jQuery: remove duplicates from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, duplicates

I have string values that contain a list of items separated with a comma, e.g. the value could be **val1,val2,val3,val1,val4,val3,val2,val5**.

Is there an easy way I can remove all duplicates from such a string so that each value only appears once within the string ?

E.g. in the above example I would like to get **val1,val2,val3,val4,val5** instead.

Many thanks in advance, Tim.

Comment: You would need a nested for loop to check each element after you split this string using string.split(","). You're probably better of checking for duplicates when you add an item to this string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make an array by split string and use [unique()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/)
try like this:

```
 data = "val1,val2,val3,val4,val5";
 arr =  $.unique(data.split(','));
 data = arr.join(","); //get unique string back with
```

[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a6NJk/684/)