# Return name string with unique values

Tags: javascript, regex, underscore.js

How would I split this string and keep only the unique values using underscore? I do need the  br  after each value.

```
Input = 'John Doe<br> John Doe<br> Frank Watts<br> '

Expected Ouput = "John Doe<br> Frank Watts<br> '
```

What I've tried so far was to split the string using

```
str.split(' ')
```

but this breaks the first and last name

Comment: So you need a string or array as the result?

Comment: The result needs to be a string

Comment: This thread could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127640/jquery-remove-duplicates-from-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using underscore:

```
var str = 'John Doe<br> John Doe<br> Frank Watts<br>',
    result = _.uniq(str.split(/\s*<br>\s*/)).join('<br> '); // "John Doe<br> Frank Watts<br> "
```

Answer (score 1):

So if you want a unique list of names you have to slit it by the `<br>` and then add to a unique set. I.e:

```
  var array = str.split('<br> '); // get a list of all the names
  var unique=array.filter(function(itm,i,array){
      return i==array.indexOf(itm);
  });
```

if you wanted to keep the `<br>` then you could just `join('<br>')` after the `split`

Answer (score 0):

From your question i have no idea what exactly you want, but if you want to split your string you can use this:

```
    var input = 'John Doe<br> John Doe<br> Frank Watts<br> '
    var arr = input.split(' ');
    console.log(arr[0]+' '+arr[1]+' '+arr[4]+' '+arr[5])
```