# Remove duplicates from string using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How i Remove duplicates from my string

```
var string="1,2,3,2,4,5,4,5,6,7,6";
```

But i want like this

```
var string="1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove occurrences of duplicate words in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843991/remove-occurrences-of-duplicate-words-in-a-string)

Comment: Show us your effort

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: remove duplicates from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127640/jquery-remove-duplicates-from-string)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it easily, Here is the working example

```
data = "1,2,3,2,4,5,4,5,6,7,6";
arr =  $.unique(data.split(','));
data = arr.join(",");

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to push unique values into a new array.

```
var names = [1,2,2,3,4,5,6];
var newNames = [];
$.each(names, function(index, value) {
    if($.inArray(value, newNames) === -1) 
        newNames.push(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the following prototype and use it to remove duplicates from any array.

```
Array.prototype.unique = function () {
    var arrVal = this;
    var uniqueArr = [];
    for (var i = arrVal.length; i--; ) {
        var val = arrVal[i];
        if ($.inArray(val, uniqueArr) === -1) {
            uniqueArr.unshift(val);
        }
    }
    return uniqueArr;
}
```

Ex:

```
var str = "1,6,7,7,8,9";
var array1 = str.split(',');
var array1 = array1.unique();
console.log(array1);    // [1,6,7,8,9]
str = array1.join();
```