# How to remove duplicates from this unique char separated string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am collecting a textbox value from a table rows. The value of textbox is varies. I'm trying to remove the duplicate from the string. I'm looking at **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127640/jquery-remove-duplicates-from-string)** accepted answer but the duplicate is still exist.

```
var memo    = "";
$("#f_sendToPic").find('#t_obj input[class=no_memo]').each(function(index, result) {
   memo +=$(this).val();
   memo += "@";
});

var val_memo = $.unique(memo.split('@'));
var arr_memo = val_memo.join('|||');

alert(memo);
alert(arr_memo);
```

I prefer browser friendly method than performance , if it's possible.

Comment: as an `@` a valid entry in the text boxes? if so you wouldn't be able to use it as a delimiter.

Comment: Also from the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/)  `Description: Sorts an array of DOM elements, in place, with the duplicates removed. Note that this only works on arrays of DOM elements, not strings or numbers.` You need to call unique on dom elements, not strings

version added: 1.1.3

Comment: @t3dodson no. I prevent special chars to be inputted to the textbox. So, the text box value maybe string, number, or combination.

Comment: Why do you append it to string and then split it again. Why don't you collect its vals into an array.

Comment: To clarify, you're talking about removing duplicate *words* or values, not duplicate *characters*, right?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I am going to save the string in a table.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes. The words between `@` need to be removed if it a duplicate.

Comment: Yeldar means, why dont you just do `arr_memo.push($(this).val())` inside your `.each` then do `var arr_memo = val_memo.join('|||');` after the loop, the whole part with joining the values with `@` then immediately splitting it on `@` seems pointless

Comment: @DelightedD0D is that method removing the duplicates?

Comment: No, nnnnn hs you covered below with that part. We just didnt understand why you were building a string just to spilt it right back apart again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an object with properties names set to the values and duplicates will automatically be filtered out. Then use `Object.keys()` to get the property names in an array and `.join()` the array to get a string with values separated by `"@"`.

```js
var working = {};
$("#f_sendToPic").find('#t_obj input[class=no_memo]').each(function() {
  working[this.value] = true;
});

var memo = Object.keys(working).join("@");

console.log(memo);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="f_sendToPic"><div id="t_obj">
  <input class="no_memo" value="abc">
  <input class="no_memo" value="def">
  <input class="no_memo" value="abc">
  <input class="no_memo" value="def">
  <input class="no_memo" value="ghi">
</div></div>
```

As an aside, note that `this.value` is easier to read, easier to type, and much more efficient to execute than `$(this).val();`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I get the expected output.

Comment: You can also use `Set` instead of object and `Object.keys`, if your code can be ES6+. It is more suitable and looks better, but is not supported by all browsers yet.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev - If the code in a question looks old-school I generally don't suggest new language features in an answer, and as you know `Set` isn't supported by IE (partial support in IE11 doesn't count). But yes, `Set` would do the same thing more neatly.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yeah, I have understood it too, so I have updated my answer :)